# How to detect the thread which is writing to a stack address?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb

I am seeing  value of the variable passed to a function is becoming null after returning from the function. The variable is pushed to the stack and while returning the same is pop. Do we have a way to find the culprit thread ? Can i protect the that stack location ? i did check the assembly and dont see any offset to rbp which may change stack ?

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
push   %rbx

.....................



add    $0x8,%rsp
pop    %rbx
leaveq
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Each stack belongs to some task (a process or a thread), so only its owning process can write into it. Show your real C code. Did you use `valgrind` or `gdb` ? Did you enable all warnings when compiling (`gcc -Wall -Wextra`)?

Comment: Thanks for looking into i have multiple threads not process.. I did edited question. Sorry for the confusion created.

Comment: Thanks nos, i did verified that none of the changes in assembly are referring bp's offset. Do you suggest any other check to find overflow ?

Comment: You might want to debug your program with `gdb` and its *watchpoints*

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in a demonstration program? Or does it only occur in a complex application?

Answer (score 1):

I think the operating system should be protecting your process from any other process messing with it's memory. Are you certain you don't have memory corruption within your program? Do you have multiple threads? Those are more likely culprits than another rogue process.

Comment: @R My fault initially i asked wrong question and edited later, meanwhile anio replied.

Answer (score 1):

Just debug the program normally. You're trying to make things much harder than they need to be.